# PyCrypto Cipher Can't Encode Character

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycrypto

I am using PyCrypto in Python 2.7 and Google's App Engine.  I am using it to encode a message which gets stored in NDB.  Generally this is not an issue, however, there are come characters that it won't accept returning the following error:

*UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\U0001f601' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)*

In the case above it is choking on an emoticon that was submitted.  I am using the following code for encryption:

```
def encypt_data(self,message,PIN):
        key = aes_key+PIN
        BS = 16
        pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)
        message = pad(message)
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
        return base64.b64encode( iv + cipher.encrypt( message ) )
```

I do want to allow the submission of these characters.  How can I accommodate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was not really with PyCrypto in this case but rather with the mixture of ASCII and Unicode characters.  This is a more general issue and my fix below also solved the problem when it came to using encryption:

```
for char in message:
   try:
      char.decode("ascii")
    except:
       msgFormat += str(char.encode("utf-8"))
     else:
        msgFormat += str(char)
```